# vue.js export declaration syntax

Tags: javascript, vue.js, syntax

I am looking at this export syntax and don't understand what it means:

```js
export default {
    name: 'my-component',
    data () {
      return {}
    }
}
```

Is this an object, a list, or what? Why is there an attribute name for `name` but nothing for the 2nd member? How does this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`export default` is the keyword used to make a [default export](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export#description).
The rest (inside of `{ }`) is the Vue instance object with key/pair values like any regular object.
It will get caught by the compiler and transformed into something reactive thanks to Vue's API.

`data()` is also equivalent to `data: function()` but we're using the ES6 shorthand here, because it's just faster and prettier to write it that way (and it does the same thing).

Otherwise, `name` is the key and `'my-component'` is the value in your example.

Answer (score 0):

This an exported object from your component script, it defines the Options API which has many fields, like `name` that represents the component's name, `data` defines the reactive data in your component and many other fields like :

- computed
- watch
- life cycle hooks such as `created`, `mounted` ....
- ...

Answer (score 0):

> Is this an object, a list, or what?

It's an object that's being exported as the default export of the module. The object has two properties:

- `name`, the string `"my-component"`
- `data`, a method that (as shown) simply returns an empty object

> Why is there an attribute name for name but nothing for the 2nd member?

The name of the second member is `data`. That's [method syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions).

More on MDN:

- [object initializer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer)
- [`export`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/export)